# reducing an Array of Float using scala.math.max

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I am confused by the following behavior - why does reducing an Array of Int work using math.max, but an Array of Float requires a wrapped function? I have memories that this was not an issue in 2.9, but I'm not completely certain about that.

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

$ scala

scala> import scala.math._

scala> Array(1, 2, 4).reduce(max)
res47: Int = 4

scala> Array(1f, 3f, 4f).reduce(max)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: (AnyVal, AnyVal) => AnyVal
          Array(1f, 3f, 4f).reduce(max)
                                   ^

scala> def fmax(a: Float, b: Float) = max(a, b)
fmax: (a: Float, b: Float)Float

scala> Array(1f, 3f, 4f).reduce(fmax)
res45: Float = 4.0
```

update : this does work

```
scala> Array(1f, 2f, 3f).reduce{(x,y) => math.max(x,y)}
res2: Float = 3.0
```

so then it is just `reduce(math.max)` which cannot be shorthanded?

Comment: somehow `reduce`'s type parameter is inferred as `AnyVal`. As a workaround, you can explicitly state it: `Array(1f, 2f, 4f).reduce[Float](math.max)`

Comment: and this is caused by method overloading (again...). If you add another `fmax` but with `Int`s, then your `reduce(fmax)` stops working as well.

Comment: Wow, just noticed that while `Array(1f, 2f, 3f).reduce(max)` fails to compile, the following works: `Array(1f, 2f, 3f).reduce(max(_,_))`. I have not even added any additional type annotation. Call me flabbergasted.

Comment: that's because `Array(1f, 2f, 3f).reduce((x,y) => max(x,y))` works. The only difference I can see is that overloading resolution is performed differently when it is applied (`max(x,y)`) rather than when it is given as a function value (eta-expansion + resolved as the type of `reduce`'s parameter). Sadly the latter is not very well described in the spec...

Comment: Doh! I had not even noticed OP's update showing that `reduce{(x,y) => math.max(x,y)}` works. This difference in type inference behaviour is really unfortunate.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing to note is that `math.max` is overloaded, and if the compiler has no hint about the expected argument types, it just picks one of the overloads (I'm not clear yet on what rules govern which overload is picked, but it will become clear before the end of this post).

Apparently it favors the overload that takes `Int`  parameters over the others.  This can be seen in the repl:

```
scala> math.max _
res6: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

That method is most specific because the first of the following compiles (by virtue of numeric widening conversions) and the second does not:

```
scala> (math.max: (Float,Float)=>Float)(1,2)
res0: Float = 2.0

scala> (math.max: (Int,Int)=>Int)(1f,2f)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Float(1.0)
 required: Int
              (math.max: (Int,Int)=>Int)(1f,2f)
                                         ^
```

The test is whether one function applies to the param types of the other, and that test includes any conversions.

Now, the question is: why can't the compiler infer the correct expected type? It certainly knows that the type of `Array(1f, 3f, 4f)` is `Array[Float]`

We can get a clue if we replace `reduce` with `reduceLeft`: then it compiles fine.

So surely this has to do with a difference in the signature of `reduceLeft` and `reduce`.
We can reproduce the error with the following code snippet:

```
case class MyCollection[A]() {
  def reduce[B >: A](op: (B, B) => B): B = ???
  def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B = ???
}
MyCollection[Float]().reduce(max) // Fails to compile
MyCollection[Float]().reduceLeft(max) // Compiles fine
```

The signatures are subtly different.

In `reduceLeft` the second argument is forced to `A` (the collection's type), so type inference is trivial: if A==Float (which the compiler knows), then the compiler knows that the only valid overload of `max` is one that takes a `Float` as its second argument. The compiler only finds one ( `max(Float,Float)` ), and it happens that the other constraint (that `B >: A`) is trivially satisfied (as `B == A == Float` for this overload).

This is different for `reduce`: both the first and second arguments can be any (same) super-type of `A` (that is, of `Float` in our specific case). This is a much more lax constraint, and while it could be argued that in this case the compiler could see that there is only one possibility, the compiler is not smart enough here.
Whether the compiler is supposed to be able to handle this case (meaning that this is an inference bug) or not, I must say I don't know. Type inference is a tricky business in scala, and as far as I know the spec is intentionally vague about what can be inferred or not.

Since there are useful applications such as:

```
scala> Array(1f,2f,3f).reduce[Any](_.toString+","+_.toString)
res3: Any = 1.0,2.0,3.0
```

trying overload resolution against every possible substitution of the type parameter is expensive and could change the result depending on the expected type you wind up with; or would it have to issue an ambiguity error?

Using `-Xlog-implicits -Yinfer-debug` shows the difference between `reduce(math.max)`, where overload resolution happens first, and the version where the param type is solved for first:

```
scala> Array(1f,2f,3f).reduce(math.max(_,_))

[solve types] solving for A1 in ?A1
inferExprInstance {
  tree      scala.this.Predef.floatArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)).reduce[A1]
  tree.tpe  (op: (A1, A1) => A1)A1
  tparams   type A1
  pt        ?
  targs     Float
  tvars     =?Float
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in the inferrer, cause with `Int` it infers types correctly:

```
private[this] val res2: Int = scala.this.Predef.intArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1, 2, 4)).reduce[Int]({
  ((x: Int, y: Int) => scala.math.`package`.max(x, y))
});
```

but with Floats:

```
private[this] val res1: AnyVal = scala.this.Predef.floatArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1.0, 3.0, 4.0)).reduce[AnyVal]({
  ((x: Int, y: Int) => scala.math.`package`.max(x, y))
});
```

If you explicitly annotate reduce with a Float type it should work:

```
Array(1f, 3f, 4f).reduce[Float](max)

private[this] val res3: Float = scala.this.Predef.floatArrayOps(scala.Array.apply(1.0, 3.0, 4.0)).reduce[Float]({
  ((x: Float, y: Float) => scala.math.`package`.max(x, y))
});
```

Comment: Why in the world would you explicitly type-annotate using `AnyVal`?

Comment: @RichardSitze didn't see his comment, i was playing with REPL

Comment: You sure it is a bug? Doesn't the specification mention it anywhere?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, namely, "why".

Answer (score 2):

There is always scala.math.Ordering:

```
Array(1f, 2f, 3f).reduceOption(Ordering.Float.max)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a bug. Consider the following code:

```
class C1 {}

object C1 {
  implicit def c2toc1(x: C2): C1 = new C1
}

class C2 {}

class C3 {
  def f(x: C1): Int = 1
  def f(x: C2): Int = 2
}

(new C3).f _                                    //> ... .C2 => Int = <function1>
```

If I remove implicit conversion I will get an error "ambiguous reference". And because `Int` has an implicit conversion to `Float` Scala tries to find the most specific type for `min`, which is `(Int, Int) => Int`. The closest common superclass for `Int` and `Float` is `AnyVal`, that's why you see `(AnyVal, AnyVal) => AnyVal`.

The reason why `(x, y) => min(x, y)` works is probably because eta-expansion is done *before* type inference and `reduce` has to deal with `(Int, Int) => Int` which will be converted to `(AnyVal, AnyVal) => AnyVal`.

**UPDATE**: Meanwhile `(new C3).f(_)` will fail with "missing parameter type" error, which means `f(_)` depends on type inference and doesn't consider implicit conversions while `f _` doesn't need parameter type and will expand to the most specific argument type if Scala can find one.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen the role of the implicit conversion in all this. How come `f _` is not ambiguous *because* `C2` can be converted to `C1`?

Comment: Oh, I see, that's SLS§6.26.3 in action. `f(x: C1)` is applicable (thanks to the implicit) to the parameter given to `f(x: C2)`, but not the other way around, so there is no ambiguity anymore, `f(x: C2)` is *more specific* (in the SLS sense) and gets picked up by overloading resolution.